# "CR LF" is displaying in my SciTE Editor (AutoIt)

Tags: autoit, scite

How to Avoid "CR LF" showing in the SciTE Editor

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl-Shift-9` should disable it

Comment: Nice to hear! Please accept it as answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Menu bar => View => Uncheck the "End of Line" option.

Or use the **shortcut** :-

```
Ctrl+Shift+9.
```